# Question on the Laplace Beltrami operator expressed by mean curvature vector: Missing term

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, laplacian

*Disclaimer*: The only course that I have seen in differential geometry is an introduction to differential geometry of manifolds and so I've never dealed with Laplace-Beltrami operator in the past.

I currently started to study a paper and at a point I came across with the following:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a $C^2-$regular boundary of an open, bounded and
>   connected subset of $\mathbb R^3$. Define the function: $\widetilde u:
>  B(x_0,r) \cap \Gamma \to \mathbb R$ as: $\widetilde u=\frac{(\alpha
>  +1)\theta}{16}{\vert x-x_0\vert}^2$
>
> Then the Laplace-Beltrami operator of $\widetilde u$ is given by:
>   $-\Delta \widetilde u= \frac{(\alpha +1)\theta}{16}(-4- H(x) \cdot
>  (x-x_0))(*)$ where $H$ denotes the mean curvature vector of $\Gamma$.

After some research I found the following formula for calculating the Laplace-Beltrami operator:

> $\Delta_{\Gamma} f=\Delta f-{\nabla}^2 f(\eta,\eta)+H_{\Gamma}\nabla
>  f$ where $\Delta$ is the usual Euclidean Laplacian and ${\nabla}^2 $
>   denotes the hessian.

**I would really appreciate if somebody could explain to me why the term ${\nabla}^2 \widetilde u (\eta,\eta)$ is missing from $(*)$.**

Thanks in advance!